# Laravel mix error when running npm run prod script in production

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix

I just finished working with my project and want to deploy it in a production server which is a cloud hosting.

When I do `npm run prod` it shows this error:

```
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn /usr/bin/node EAGAIN
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:362:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ production script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/prismac1/.npm/_logs/2020-02-17T21_12_19_364Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ prod: `npm run production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/prismac1/.npm/_logs/2020-02-17T21_12_19_383Z-debug.log
```

However, when I try to do it on my local machine it works just fine. Any solution for this?

Please take a look at the debug log as well:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'prod' ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v8.17.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preprod', 'prod', 'postprod' ]
5 info lifecycle @~preprod: @
6 info lifecycle @~prod: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~prod: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~prod: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/prismac1/public_html/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/home/prismac1/.local/bin:/home/prismac1/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~prod: CWD: /home/prismac1/public_html
10 silly lifecycle @~prod: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run production' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~prod: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~prod: Failed to exec prod script
13 verbose stack Error: @ prod: `npm run production`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /home/prismac1/public_html
16 verbose Linux 3.10.0-962.3.2.lve1.5.27.el7.x86_64
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "prod"
18 verbose node v8.17.0
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ prod: `npm run production`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ prod script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: unless you are running an actual node server or that you really have the requirement to compile on production, there's no real reason to compile this on production ... I would run `npm run production` on my dev environment, commit that, and pull that into the server, specially if you are on a server in which you don't have many permissions.

Comment: I agree, I did that too for now, but I was affraid it will leads to another problem in the future. Is it safe enough to do this without fixing the source of the problem?

Comment: If you are on an actual cloud provider, where you can actually ssh into your server, and run sudo commands, you can try sudo npm... but I really don't see the point, the compiled code is javascript that runs on the client machine, not on the server. The compiled code, shouldn't care too much, or anything about the server is being hosted on, unless is code that's going to run on the server, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I see, I think I'll stick with that. Thanks a lot for your explanation.